# Where is the Java installation that is installed by Java Updater located?

Tags: macos, command-line, java, osx-yosemite

I am running OS X Yosemite. I add Java to my path in `.bashrc` like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

`/user/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` points me to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home`.

This sets my "default" JDK to be 1.8.0_74. I'm not sure where this JDK came from. I think it shipped with Yosemite.

Separately, Java Updater runs periodically and updates Java. Currently it says I am on 1.8.0_161:

[image]

But I can't find it on my computer anywhere! It's not inside `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. I tried `find / -name java -type f` and still couldn't find it. Where is it?

Comment: Does `pkgutil --pkgs | egrep -i 'oracle|java|jdk|jre'` show any relevant packages installed?

Comment: I did not know `pkgutil` existed. The output is (sorry all one line): `com.apple.pkg.JavaEssentials
com.apple.pkg.JavaForMacOSX107
com.apple.pkg.JavaMDNS
com.apple.pkg.JavaSecurity
com.apple.pkg.JavaTools
com.oracle.jdk7u67
com.oracle.jdk8u25
com.oracle.jdk8u74
com.oracle.jre`

Comment: `com.oracle.jdk7u67 com.oracle.jdk8u25 com.oracle.jdk8u74` are the ones in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Comment: Looks like running it with `--files` against `com.oracle.jre` shows some files that suggest it's 1.8.0_161 (the desired version), and running it with `| grep bin` shows `java` exists in `Contents/Home/bin/java`. Trying to figure out where that is.

Comment: Survey says: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/31588/12843 (the root of the installation is `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just install the JRE it goes in `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/`

If you install the JDK it goes in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

The JRE is not much use for general Java usage as it is only available in browsers. You need the JDK to run normal Java programs or things like Eclipse.